# How can I get my progress bar to update while running code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have some code I'm trying to run while updating a progress bar but instead it runs my code, then the bar fills.  I'm using background worker but I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.  I have Visual Studio 2019.  It's telling me it needs more details to post this question, but there isn't much else to post.

````
       txtBrantTrans.Text = Get_Transaction_Number("Brantford")
       txtCambTrans.Text = Get_Transaction_Number("Cambridge")
       txtParisTrans.Text = Get_Transaction_Number("Paris")
       txtWoodTrans.Text = Get_Transaction_Number("Woodstock")

       txtSite.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime(" "), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite00.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("00"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite01.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("01"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite02.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("02"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite03.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("03"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite04.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("04"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite05.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("05"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite06.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("06"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite07.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("07"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite08.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("08"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite09.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("09"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite10.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("10"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite12.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("12"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite14.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("14"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite15.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("15"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite16.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("16"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
       txtSite17.Text = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("17"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")


       Change_Colour(txtSite)
       Change_Colour(txtSite00)
       Change_Colour(txtSite01)
       Change_Colour(txtSite02)
       Change_Colour(txtSite03)
       Change_Colour(txtSite04)
       Change_Colour(txtSite05)
       Change_Colour(txtSite06)
       Change_Colour(txtSite07)
       Change_Colour(txtSite08)
       Change_Colour(txtSite09)
       Change_Colour(txtSite10)
       Change_Colour(txtSite12)
       Change_Colour(txtSite14)
       Change_Colour(txtSite15)
       Change_Colour(txtSite16)
       Change_Colour(txtSite17)
   End Sub

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
       'Fill_Form()
       bgwFillInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = True
       bgwFillInfo.RunWorkerAsync()
   End Sub

   Private Sub bgwFillInfo_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwFillInfo.DoWork
       Me.Invoke(Sub() Fill_Form())
       For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
           If i Mod 1000 Then
               bgwFillInfo.ReportProgress(i / 100)
           End If
       Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub bgwFillInfo_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwFillInfo.ProgressChanged
       pbFillInfo.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
   End Sub```
````

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to execute code on a background thread but the very first thing you do on that thread is `Invoke` a method back on the UI thread, so it's utterly useless. What you should be doing is getting all the data first, then updating your UI. Call all those methods and assign the results to variables on the background thread, then update the UI on the UI thread.

Comment: Also, you should not be calling `Invoke` at all if you're using a `BackgroundWorker`, which is the whole point.

Comment: If you're really determined to do it using a `BackgroundWorker` and updating the UI as you go, what you should be doing is getting one data item and then passing it to the UI thread via a call to `ReportProgress`, so you update the appropriate `TextBox` and the `ProgressBar` each time.

Comment: Please don't edit your question so significantly that it renders existing posted answers irrelevant. If you have incorporated jmc's answer into your project but you're still stuck, you should **upvote it, accept it and *ask another question***

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This is my first day on this page and first post so I'm learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might update the UI in the `ProgressChanged` event handler while doing the rest of the work in the `DoWork` event handler.

`DoWork`:

```vb
Dim textBoxes = {TextBox1, TextBox2, ..., TextBoxN}

For i = 0 To textBoxes.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim progress = (i + 1) * 100 \ textBoxes.Length
    Dim data = GetData()
    Dim packet = Tuple.Create(textBoxes(i), data)

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress, packet)
Next
```

`ProgressChanged`:

```vb
Dim packet = DirectCast(e.UserState, Tuple(Of TextBox, String))
Dim textBox = packet.Item1
Dim data = packet.Item2

textBox.Text = data

ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
```

You do the work of getting the data on the background thread and then you pass the data, the control to update with that data and the current progress, then you update that control with the data and the `ProgressBar` on the UI thread. You can package up the control and the data in whatever way you deem appropriate. I've used a `Tuple` here but you might choose to use an array or your own dedicated type.

Comment: I think I'm getting a bit closer, but I don't know how to run ReportProgress or where to put that code.  That doesn't exist as a sub under BackGroundWorker

Comment: I told you where to put it. The first code snippet demonstrates the sort of code you need to put in the `DoWork` event handler and the second snippet is the sort of code you need in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I wrote `ReportProgress` when I meant `ProgressChanged`, although I did say `ProgressChanged` before that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: On the Dim packet = DirectCast(e.UserState.....line I'm getting the following error
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Tuple`2[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Tuple`2[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox,System.String]'."} System.InvalidCastException

Comment: @Andrew, I just provided an example. If your data is type `Integer` then you obviously need to cast as type `Tuple(Of TextBox, Integer)`. I just assumed `String` because that's what goes in a `TextBox`. Please take the time to understand the concepts first, then implement the code as appropriate. The idea is that you package up YOUR data, so you need to use the types that are appropriate for YOUR data.

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I really appreciate your help but you should understand that people are coming here for help.  They might not understand the concepts which is why they came here.  Some people might not want to be talked down to.

Answer (score 0):

With JM's help I was able to get it working amazingly.  Here is my code for anyone who wants an example

My refresh button does this but you could also do this on form load

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
        bgwFillInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgwFillInfo.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
```

Then the DoWork of the BackGroundWork is this

```
Private Sub bgwFillInfo_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwFillInfo.DoWork
        Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {txtBrantTrans, txtCambTrans, txtParisTrans, txtWoodTrans, txtSite, txtSite00, txtSite01, txtSite02, txtSite03, txtSite04, txtSite05, txtSite06, txtSite07, txtSite08, txtSite09, txtSite10, txtSite12, txtSite14, txtSite15, txtSite16, txtSite17}
        Dim locname As String = ""
        Dim data As String = ""
        For i = 0 To textBoxes.GetUpperBound(0)
            Dim progress = (i + 1) * 100 \ textBoxes.Length
            Select Case textBoxes(i).Name
                Case "txtBrantTrans"
                    data = Get_Transaction_Number("Brantford").ToString
                Case "txtCambTrans"
                    data = Get_Transaction_Number("Cambridge").ToString
                Case "txtParisTrans"
                    data = Get_Transaction_Number("Paris").ToString
                Case "txtWoodTrans"
                    data = Get_Transaction_Number("Woodstock").ToString
                Case "txtSite"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime(" "), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite00"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("00"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite01"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("01"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite02"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("02"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite03"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("03"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite04"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("04"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite05"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("05"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite06"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("06"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite07"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("07"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite08"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("08"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite09"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("09"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite10"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("10"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite12"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("12"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite14"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("14"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite15"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("15"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite16"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("16"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString
                Case "txtSite17"
                    data = Format(Get_Last_Transaction_DateTime("17"), "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").ToString

            End Select
            Dim packet = Tuple.Create(textBoxes(i), data)

            bgwFillInfo.ReportProgress(progress, packet)
        Next
    End Sub
```

The ProgressChanged of the BackGroundWork looks like this

```
Private Sub bgwFillInfo_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwFillInfo.ProgressChanged
        Dim packet = DirectCast(e.UserState, Tuple(Of TextBox, String))
        Dim textBox = packet.Item1
        Dim data = packet.Item2

        textBox.Text = data
        Change_Colour(textBox)

        pbFillInfo.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    End Sub
```